# Not receiving ICMPv6 "packet too big" messages from virtual router

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, icmp

I am running `GNS3` (0.8.3.1) with `VirtualBox 4.2.6` guest running `Ubuntu 12.10` and I realized a problem with `ICMPv6` packets.

My `PMTUD` application is not receiving "packet too big" messages from the virtual Cisco c3660 router. I have 2 host-only adapters in VirtualBox and my tiny virtual network is working fine with `IPv4 PMTUD`. But when i tried to implement `IPv6 PMTUD`, I realized the above. I am not filtering any `ICMPv6` packets and the router has only basic configuration, ip, ipv6 address, no shut and set mtu.

Is it a bug in my program, `GNS3/VirtualBox/Ubuntu` or is the router configuration wrong (i have not set any filter)? I would appreciate if someone could check if he is getting `ICMPv6` "packet too big" messages on similar configuration so we could sort out a bug in `GNS3/VirtualBox/Ubuntu`.

Thank you for any help.